# How do I abort execution after encountering error?

Tags: java, c++, cmd, exe

At the moment I use a simple cmd start command. So:
start ../myexe.exe parameters

As you can see this exe is created from a cpp solution.
When an error occurres I get a pop up like this:

[image]

But I actually want this to abort automatically, because it should run in the background totally. Is there a way to run an exe like this? Should I change something in the cpp solution? Or should I write some kind of script to abort the execution?

Another spin of the problem is, that I need to run the exe in a java project. Should I change something here? The implementation so far:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /B /wait "
                    + BASE_PATH
                    + "/ciff_caff_parser.exe "
                    + caffFullPath + " "
                    + caffId
                    + " || exit /b");
            logger.info("Waiting for parser to finish...");
            int i = process.waitFor();
            logger.info("Parser finished successfully, with error code: " + i);
```

Comment: You really should fix the error first.  There is something wrong with `ciff_caff_parser.exe`.

Comment: *I need to run the exe in a java project* That is almost certainly the wrong way to do whatever you're trying to do. Why do you think you want to do that?

Comment: That's the requirement for my homework :(

Comment: Also, note that you are running a debug version of `ciff_caff_parser.exe`.  That means that if you were to build a release version, you won't receive that dialog box anyway.  Instead you would have a buggy program running in the background, if it already hasn't crashed.

Comment: @KurdiBoti *That's the requirement for my homework :(* -- So your requirement is to get a broken program to run in the background?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It's a parser (i did not wrote it) if it gets a file which is not valid it should fail. And then we should notice the user that the file is not parsable. It seems ok to me. But you already answered my question. If the release version won't show these messages.

Comment: Do you know why the debug version failed?  How do you know it failed because the file was not valid?  And if you have the source code, why not fix it so that the exit is done gracefully instead of a hard-crash (or assert)?  There is a `Retry` button -- have you pressed it to see what happens?  In C++, the release version may not even crash, but do unexpected things (like format your hard drive).  You need to know exactly why that error occurs.

Comment: *It's a parser (i did not wrote it)* -- Get the author to fix the program.

Comment: I created an invalid file to test the functionality. What should I fix? The parser to fail nicer? If we know that the parser failed, we don't need to know why. As far as I understand.

Comment: That is totally wrong.  If the program fails for the reason that is given in that dialog, then the program is in undefined behavior land.  That's how C++ works.  There is no guarantee of a crash for that or any other error.  C++ is not Java.  That's why the C++ program must be fixed.

Comment: I do not believe that we should be finding out that this is homework, part way through the comment section. Please take a look at [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822), which should provide useful advice about homework questions. You appear to have asked us to solve your homework problem for you, as opposed to assisting you with your own attempted solution!

Comment: @Compo I didn't ask any of you to solve my homework (which was incomparably more difficult than the question I asked). The question was targeted to solve a specific issue, which only made my homework a little better. But as PaulMcKenzie highligted it would still need some work on the parser side :D